# Play one video at a time on html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html page.
I have used a video tag for playing video online
I have used two video tags,
But when I play both videos, then
both videos play at same time

I want a solution that, if I play one video and then click on the second one then the first one should be paused and the second one starts playing.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show us your code, without code its hard to assume everything. And how can you click both video at same time `when i click on both video` explain this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Vanilla js here.

```js
var videos = document.querySelectorAll('video');
for(var i=0; i<videos.length; i++)
   videos[i].addEventListener('play', function(){pauseAll(this)}, true);


function pauseAll(elem){
 for(var i=0; i<videos.length; i++){
  //Is this the one we want to play?
  if(videos[i] == elem) continue;
  //Have we already played it && is it already paused?
  if(videos[i].played.length > 0 && !videos[i].paused){
  // Then pause it now
    videos[i].pause();
  }
 }
  }
```

```html
<video height="169" width="300" preload="none" controls="controls">
  <source type="video/webm" src="http://video.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm"></source>
  <source type="video/mp4" src="http://video.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.mp4"></source>
</video>


<video height="169" width="300" preload="none" controls="controls">
  <source type="video/webm" src="http://video.webmfiles.org/elephants-dream.webm"></source>
  <source type="video/mp4" src="https://archive.org/download/ElephantsDream/ed_hd.mp4"></source>
</video>
```

Comment: can u help me if I am using iframes and loading vimeo videos?

Answer (score 4):

One simple solution will be using javascript. Apply play binding to the video tag. In that pause all the other video

```
$('video').bind('play', function (e) 
{
    var video = $('video');
    for(var i=0;i<video.length;i++)
    {
        if(video[i] != e.target)
        {
           video[i].pause();
        }
    }
});
```

Not sure but hope it will work for you

Answer (score 3):

```js
 // AUTO STOP WHEN CURRENT VIDEO IS PLAYING..

//JAVASCRIPT

    document.addEventListener('play', function(e){
      var videos = document.getElementsByTagName('video');
      for(var i = 0, len = videos.length; i < len;i++){
          if(videos[i] != e.target){
              videos[i].pause();
          }
      }
    }, true);
    
  ///REACT
  
 // componentDidMount() {
  //  document.addEventListener('play', function(e){
    //  var videos = document.getElementsByTagName('video');
   //   for(var i = 0, len = videos.length; i < len;i++){
     //     if(videos[i] != e.target){
      //        videos[i].pause();
      //    }
   //   }
  //  }, true);
    
 // }
```

```html
<video height="169" width="300" preload="none" controls="controls">
  <source type="video/webm"   src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"></source>
</video>


<video height="169" width="300" preload="none" controls="controls">
  <source type="video/webm"   src="https://archive.org/download/ElephantsDream/ed_hd.mp4"></source>
</video>
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to monitor the video's `"play"` event, and when it fires you stop the other video. that way, when you play one video in whatever way, the other one will stop:

```js
$(function(){
    $("#video1").on("play",function(){
        $("#video2").trigger("pause");
    });
    $("#video2").on("play",function(){
        $("#video1").trigger("pause");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video id="video1" width="300" controls="" onplay="Vid1()">
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video>

<video id="video2" width="300" controls=""><br>
  <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm" type="video/webm"><br>
  <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv" type="video/ogg"><br>
  <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4"><br>
  <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.3gp" type="video/3gp"><br>
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
onplay="stopOtherMedia(this)"
```

on all audio and video tags

```
function stopOtherMedia(element) {
    $("audio").not(element).each(function(index, audio) {
        audio.pause();
    });

    $("video").not(element).each(function(index, video) {
        video.pause();
    });

}
```