# how to auto stop a video in a html page when another video is played in the same page

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a small project that needs many videos to be on the same page . I just can't get a video to pause when another video is played in the same page. Can anyone help me? It does not include any fancy JavaScript .its just plain html.
here is some of my example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Videos | MCloud | Your Music Place</title>



</head>
<body>

<HEADER>
<a href="/" title="MCloud"><img src="images/logo.jpg" height="70"></a> <div 
style="width:1500px;height:50px;border:1px solid #000 ; background-color: 
#F5D0A9"><h4 align="center"><a href="MCloud_home.html">Home</a> | <a 
href="#">Latest English Songs</a> | <a href="#">Latest Bollywood Songs</a> | 
<a href="#">Latest Bangla songs</a> | </h4> 
 </h4>
</div>


<h4>Like Music? And Like Videos?? Here Are some Reccomendations</h4>

<table>
<tr>
    <td><video controls height="160" width="300"><source src="videos/Post 
Malone - Psycho ft. Ty Dolla $ign.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video></td>
    <td><video controls height="160" width="300"><source src="videos/James 
Yammouni & Faydee - On My Way ft. Adam Saleh (Official Music Video).mp4" 
type="video/mp4"></video></td>
    <td><video controls height="160" width="300"><source 
src="videos/maroon5-wait.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video></td>
    <td><video controls height="160" width="300"><source 
src="videos/maroon5-payphone.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video></td>
    <td><video controls height="160" width="300"><source src="videos/The 
Chainsmokers & Coldplay - Something Just Like This (Lyric).mp4" 
type="video/mp4"></video></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Play one video at a time on html page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27984325/play-one-video-at-a-time-on-html-page)

Comment: no those did not work... TIA

Comment: Could you include some of your HTML in the question please?